Filter date column in Rsqlite
Trying to filter on a date column using RSQLite but it does not seem  to work. Where is it going wrong?
library(RSQLite)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

test_db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "", extended_types = TRUE)

df <- tibble(date_col = ymd(c("2018-01-01", "2019-01-01")))

dbWriteTable(test_db, "df", df)

# Column is date
dbSendQuery(test_db, "PRAGMA table_info(df)") %>% dbFetch()

dbSendQuery(test_db, "SELECT * FROM df WHERE date_col = '2019-01-01'") %>% dbFetch()
dbSendQuery(test_db, "SELECT * FROM df WHERE date_col = date('2019-01-01')") %>% dbFetch()


Wrap ymd() in as_date() in the df tibble.

You have just two rows of data and one column in your tibble. What exactly are you filtering?

I want to filter on one of the rows. The output should be 1 row with date_col = 2019-01-01

SQLite does not have a native date type which makes date processing with it somewhat onerous. Just about every other SQL database does have date types.

Since RSQLite has no date datatype, just avoid using R dates in the tibble:
df <- tibble(date_col = c("2018-01-01", "2019-01-01"))

dbWriteTable(test_db, "df", df)

dbSendQuery(test_db, "SELECT * FROM df WHERE date_col = '2019-01-01'") %>% dbFetch()
#----results-----
    date_col
1 2019-01-01

If you want a db that has a date type and whose engine is included in its R package, you can install duckdb, but I will warn you to definitely install a binary version unless you are exceptionally patient. The installation from source takes a realllllllly long time.
